# Copy files from multiple directories and create same structure in other separate folder [Windows]

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I would like for someone please to help me create a script (batch/powershell maybe?) to copy multiple files from different sources and paste them in a separate private folder (MyStackedFiles for instance) from a TXT file list.

**Example TXT File:**

```
"C:\Windows\System32\File1.dll"

"C:\Windows\System32\File2.dll"

"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySoftware\Main.exe"
```

**Example copied data output:**

```
"C:\Users\me\Desktop\MyStackedFiles\Windows\System32\File1.dll"

"C:\Users\me\Desktop\MyStackedFiles\Windows\System32\File2.dll"

"C:\Users\me\Desktop\MyStackedFiles\Program Files (x86)\MySoftware\Main.exe"
```

***The code that I made so far, but it doesn't make structure***

```
@echo off
For /F "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('type "C:\MyListwSources.txt"') 
    DO xcopy /hrkvy "%%a" "C:\MyFolder"
PAUSE
```

Thank you!

Comment: Type `xcopy /?`.

Comment: Your question is off topic, this is not a free code request service. 'Help me' implies that you're also performing some work. Please post the script you have written, which you'd like us to help you with and we'll try to assist you.

Comment: Thank you for supplying your code. You are copying individual files from their locations, _(read from Example TXT File)_, to `C:\Users\me\Desktop\MyStackedFiles`, so I fully expect the following results `C:\Users\me\Desktop\MyStackedFiles\File1.dll` `C:\Users\me\Desktop\MyStackedFiles\File2.dll` and `C:\Users\me\Desktop\MyStackedFiles\Main.exe`. Perhaps you'd be better trying `XCopy /HRKVY "%%~a" "C:\Users\me\Desktop\MyStackedFiles%%~pa"` instead. This would suffix the full path of each file, minus the drive specifier, to each destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, a single line batch file should do as you intended, *(just change `C:\MyListwSources.txt` as necessary)*:

```bat
@(For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%I In ('Type "C:\MyListwSources.txt"')Do @"%__AppDir__%xcopy.exe" /HRKVY "%%~I" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\MyStackedFiles%%~pI")&Pause
```

Take a look at the output from `for /?`, *(entered at the Command Prompt)*, to see the `for` variable expansion modifiers and what each does.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It worked! Just to clarify for future readers you just need to paste the code in .BAT file extension and if you are copying from Windows System (for instance System32) you need obviously to "Run as Admin" or run elevated CMD/Powershell

Comment: My suggestion is to use the `.cmd` extension in preference to `bat`.

Answer (score 0):

## Batch Style

```
@Echo Off
For /F "Tokens=* Delims= " %%a In ('Type TXTFileContainingPaths.txt') Do (
  For /F "Tokens=* Delims= " %%b In ('Type TXTFileContainingDestinationPaths.txt') Do (
     %__APPDIR__%Xcopy.exe "%%~fa" "%%~fb"
  )
)
```

## Explanation

- It gets the paths from two text files containing source and destination paths using `For` commands.
- Xcopy command copies the files.

For more understanding, open cmd and enter these commands and read carefully:

- `For /?`
- `Xcopy /?`
- `Type /?`

Comment: How can I identify which questions are clearly off-topic? I will try to prohibit from doing this